# Compare two Pandas Columns with Another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a master dataframe `df1` which has unique column combinations (`'a'` and `'b'`)

```
df1:
a   b
A   1 
B   4 
K   5
```

I want to use these combinations to compare `df2`, iterating through each column and returning `True` or `False` based on whether the combination in `df2` matches that of `df1`.

```
 df2:
a   b   c
A   1   TRUE
B   4   TRUE
K   1   FALSE
```

For example the 3rd row in `df2` K, 1 does not match the K value in `df1` (K,5). Just fyi, the number of rows will be larger for `df2`

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator` parameter and then compare by `both` value for boolean column:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1, on=['a','b'], how='left',indicator='c')
df3['c'] = df3['c'].eq('both')

print (df3)
   a  b      c
0  A  1   True
1  B  4   True
2  K  1  False
```